# How to call a constructor from another class using the argument for a method in the current class?

Tags: java

I need to be able to call the constructor of an inheriting class depending on what is input for the method newInstance(String kind)... my code currently looks like this:

```
public class Animal {


public String kind;
public String integument;

protected Animal(){

}

public Animal newInstance(String kind){
    kind x = new kind();
    return x;
}
```

So for instance, if the String put in was "owl", I want it to call the constructor in my previously created owl class and create a new owl instance. The owl class looks like:

```
public class Owl extends Bird{

public Owl(){
    this.kind = "owl";
}

public void newOwl(){
}

@Override
public String sound(){
    return "'Hoot'";
}


}
```

Right now I get an error that says, "class kind is not found" because it is looking for a class called kind, rather than waiting for an input and looking for a class called the same thing as the string input.

How can I rewrite this code so that the input in that method will look for a class by that name and create a new object of that type? Thanks!

Comment: You could use `Class.forName(kind).newInstance()`, which does exactly what you've described.  But that's probably not a very good solution to your problem.  What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: Maybe you want a simple switch using kind? `switch(kind) { case "owl": return new Owl(); }`

Comment: You should probably implement `Animal.newInstance()` as a [Factory Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).  A little more detail would help us narrow down the wide range of possibilities here.

Comment: I cannot make much sense of your code.  Could you please re-check (and also re-format) it?  For example, the `newInstance` method you show calls a `kind` constructor and returns its result as an `Animal`.  That looks definitely wrong.  A complete example would help.

Comment: In real applications, you would normally need to initialize each subclass in a different way (i.e. passing different arguments to the constructors, or using some other logic as opposed to just a class name). So the `switch` becomes the best way.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use what's called a [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), in another class entirely or as a static method on `Animal`:

```
public class Animal {
    public static Animal getInstance(final String kind) {
        if(kind== null) {
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must provide a name");
        }
        switch(kind.toLowerCase()) {
           case "owl": return new Owl();
           case "deer": return new Deer();
           default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't create a " + kind);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Calling String.toLowerCase() without specifying a locale is asking for trouble.

Comment: @dnault Indeed depending on the inputs, but I was trying not to confuse the issue with that. Very good point though.